# Publishing npm module on Verdaccio from Docker gitlab CI

Tags: docker, npm, gitlab, gitlab-ci, verdaccio

I am trying to publish a module on my private Verdaccio repository from Gitlab CI running in Docker. I followed [this tutorial](https://andrepolischuk.com/how-to-start-using-gitlab-ci/) and I generated the token on my host (because the container which will run jobs does not exist until the pipeline starts).

```
image: node:11-alpine

stages:
  - test
  - publish

before_script: 
  - npm set registry http://nodejs.repo.asts.com
  - npm i

test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - npm run lint
    - npm t
  coverage: '/All files\s*\|\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?)/'

publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "//nodejs.repo.asts.com/:_authToken=\"$NPM_AUTH_TOKEN\"" > ~/.npmrc
    - cat ~/.npmrc
    - npm whoami
    - npm publish
```

The job fails with following error:

```
$ npm whoami
npm ERR! code ENEEDAUTH
npm ERR! need auth this command requires you to be logged in.
npm ERR! need auth You need to authorize this machine using `npm adduser`
```

But the `cat` command shows that the token has expected value.

I do not understand if the problem is that Verdaccio does not support tokens or the way I generated it. I also found a [plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/verdaccio-gitlab-ci) but I cannot figure out how should be used.

How should I configure my gitlab CI to publish a package on Verdaccio?

Comment: I have no a real answer, but I know where you can start https://github.com/verdaccio/docker-examples/tree/master/gitlab-verdaccio and whom ask, please check the committers

Comment: Instead of writing .npmrc to the user folder write it in the current folder you want to publish your module from.

Comment: Also interested in this. @JuanPicado, there is no official docs about Gitlab CI and Verdaccio?

Comment: @Nikita no, only plugins are within our GitHub organization I could guaranty some documentation or quick help in our chat. Gitlab is the most popular one and I contribute time on time, but I don't use it.

Comment: @JuanPicado thanks for the response. Finally it was easier than expected, and actually hedge provided a working solution that I failed to check. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work as @Hedge said: saving the token in a `.npmrc` file in the project folder:

```
image: node:11-alpine

stages:
  - test
  - publish

before_script: 
  - npm set registry http://nodejs.repo.asts.com
  - npm i

test:
  stage: test
  script: 
    - npm run lint
    - npm t
  coverage: '/All files\s*\|\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d+)?)/'

publish:
  stage: publish
  script:
    - echo "//nodejs.repo.asts.com/:_authToken=\"$NPM_AUTH_TOKEN\"" > .npmrc
    - npm whoami
    - npm publish
```

Comment: Thanks, the solution is a conjunction between your answer and a lack of knowledge about Gitlab protected tags (https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/3057).